# What is the best way to cast Hololens to a PC without delay?

Tags: casting, wifi, hololens

I am working in a showroom, and need to stream the Hololens experience to a PC which is then connected to a large screen over WiFi. On the PC I am using Hololens Companion App. We coupled two Hololens 2 to the app. But on the livestream we experience sometimes that the cast is coming late for some seconds or it hangs completely on the PC.
Is there a possibly a more performant way to do a casting from the Hololens to the PC - possibly using a different app or a hardware ? This would help us a lot. Thank you in advance !

Best regards

Karsten

Comment: Hi Karsten, this question doesn't appear to be related to programming. I recommend you recreate the question on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

To share the first-person perspective as a video stream for the local user, you can also leverage built-in Miracast support to stream videos to the display receivers(such as your PC). For more information, please refer to Mixed Reality official doc:[Shared experiences in mixed reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/shared-experiences-in-mixed-reality#share-first-person-perspective).